# How to show Data inside of String with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to show the data inside of the string data in ASP.net mvc 4.

```
@{
    string data = "test";

    @:<span>
    @ data
            @:</span>
}
```

I don't know how to do it?

In this context I need to have "@{" and @:

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{
    string data = "test";

    @:<span>
    @(data)
            @:</span>
}
```